# gnome-terminal highlight URLs ending in close-paren

Tags: 14.04, gnome, gnome-terminal, url, syntax-highlighting

When `gnome-terminal` 3.6.2 highlights a URL ending in `)`, it incorrectly omits that `)`.  Such URLs are found in wikis with disambiguation pages, such as [`http://zelda.gamepedia.com/Ocarina_of_Time_(Item)`](http://zelda.gamepedia.com/Ocarina_of_Time_(Item)), or thousands more in Wikipedia.

How can this be fixed?

Related: [Disable hyperlinks in gnome-terminal](https://askubuntu.com/questions/671278/disable-hyperlinks-in-gnome-terminal)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strictly speaking this is not incorrect per se, since there is no standard describing how to locate the exact boundaries of a link inside a text. It's a bit of guesswork, and as such, there will always be cases when it doesn't exactly do what you're hoping for.

URLs sometimes appear inside parantheses, e.g. `(http://example.com)`, and here the desired behavior is to exclude the closing parenthesis.

The regular expressions that locate URLs were completely rewritten in `gnome-terminal` version 3.18.3. However, the new behavior isn't what you're looking for either. The new behavior terminates the URL before the `(` character.

These regexes are not configurable, you have to edit `gnome-terminal`'s source code and recompile in order to change them.

Update: In [bug 763980](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=763980) we further improved `gnome-terminal` to correctly handle both cases. Beginning with version 3.25.1, it allows balanced pairs of parentheses in URLs. As such, in `http://example.com/foo_(bar)` (or in your example) the trailing parenthesis will be part of the URL, whereas in `(http://example.com/foo)` it won't.